# Unit testing for FirefoxOS packaged app

Tags: unit-testing, firefox-os

I want to write a unit testing code for a Firefox OS packaged app.

src/manifest.webapp
src/app.html
src/app.js
test/manifest.webapp
test/unittest.html
test/unittest.js

Is there a way to load app.js from unittest.html?

```
<script src="../src/app.js"></script>
```

This doesn't work when I launch unittest.html as a packaged app.

Answer (score 0):

Made an example and it works for me. Take a look at https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/134884/packagedtest.zip . I tried it in a Firefox 1.2 Simulator using the App Manager from Firefox Nightly, if it makes any difference.

Something else must be the issue. Use the developer tools to connect to the simulator to see if there are any relevant errors in the console. If you are using the App Manager, just click the "Debug" button bellow the app to do that. If you are using the Simulator 1.1 add-on, click the "Connect" button next to the app.

Comment: manifest.webapp in your file is for unit testing. When you launch the app, you have to change the value of launch_path in it. But I want to make unit testing files without changing app files.

Comment: You can change the manifest to launch /one/index.html (the app in your case) and click the link to go to /two/index.html (or the test runner in your case) and it should work.